# Making mapnik verbose?

Tags: postgis, mapnik

I've got a PostGIS NHD layer thats not rendering in mapnik (using toposm code scripts) and I don't know why.

I've confirmed that the table data is there, positioned correctly and has the proper projection via QGIS, and the styles seem to have the table names correctly, but I'm still getting a features layer without my nhd water features.

Is there a way I can tell mapnik.render to spit out the queries its running against my PostGIS db?   Is there another way to debug this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can build Mapnik to enable all postgres queries details to be output. See https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/Runtime-Logging for more details.

However, it is easiest to just enable logging of postgres itself. One way that I frequently do this is to launch postgres from the command line like:

`postgres -D /path/to/postgres/directory -c log_min_duration_statement=0`